# Access company jira server with python-jira using certificates

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate, jira, python-jira

My company uses its own multi-factor authentication to login to our jira server. Everything I have searched for only suggests how to connect to the server using username/password or an api-token. But I need to use our generated certificates to try and connect.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import requests
from atlassian import Jira


#certificates for request
CERT = '/path/to/cert'
KEY = '/path/to/key'

session = requests.Session()
session.cert = (CERT, KEY)
session.timeout = 5

jira = Jira(
   url="url",
   session=session)

issue = jira.issue('issue')
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, if not work please can you contact with me provide me your email

```
import os
import requests
from atlassian import Jira


#certificates for request
CERT = '/path/to/cert'
KEY = '/path/to/key'

session = requests.Session()
session.cert = (CERT, KEY)
session.timeout = 5

jira = Jira(
   url="url",
   session=session)
# add this code 
jira.verify_ssl = False

issue = jira.issue('issue')
```

Comment: could you add a little more about how this Answers the Question? presumably the intent is that setting `.verify_ssl` skips the SSL checks in the client

Comment: this mean your cert maked by you, you need buy one or get free one from this site -> ssl.com

Comment: this not problem if you set `verify_ssl = False` its not mean the ssl is disabled